# The usage of "and" between adjectives

Tags: adjectives, usage, conjunctions

> This car is  fantastic and old.

Did I make any mistake by putting *and* between these two adjectives since they are from different categories?

Comment: No mistake. You may link adjectives as items in a list, e.g. this car is fantastic, fast, comfortable, old, and red.

Comment: Please provide research. Otherwise, the questions are worthless and you are wasting our time. Start by looking up the word *and* in a dictionary and posting it.

Comment: @Lambie, as I read the question, it isn't about the meaning of _and_, but about syntactic/semantic limitations on coordination. I'd be surprised if a dictionary gave any relevant information about that.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, Colin, okay, but still some effort on their part, right?

Comment: It's weird and unnatural without a context that justifies the yoking  of such disparate adjectives. That would be true in any language,. It is not ungrammatical. However, "grammatical" is a low bar.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as a slightly surprising thing to say, but I can find no fault with it either grammatically or stylistically.

Native speakers don't even think about "categories" of adjectives (I had never heard of them until I started reading this site, and found that ESL learners would talk about them). I don't know if there is any tendency against coordinating adjectives from different categories.

Comment: I can imagine thinking of adjectives describing these qualities as perhaps belonging to 'categories': opinion, size, age, shape, colour, origin, material, purpose.

Comment: It's the contrast in the adjectives that cries out for *but* instead of *and*.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no mistake here, you could have said "This is a fantastic old car."

When used attributively (before the noun) you can order the adjectives like this. You could also say "This is a fantastic and old car"*. But when used in the predicate you need to use "and":  "This car is fantastic and old".

While "fantastic old car" seems natural enough.  It seems odd to say "is fantastic and old", because these are two random pieces of information that don't seem to relate to each other, and in fact might contrast with each other.  "The car is old but fantastic" seems more likely.

* <sub>There is a nuance difference, "fantastic old car" is an old car that is fantastic, "fantastic and old car" is a car that is fantastic and old"</sub>